# how to copy file from my local pc into my android phone?

Tags: file-copy, android

I want to copy a file from my local pc into my android phone.The android phone was be read as `gphoto2://[usb:001,009]/`

```
mv  test.mp4  gphoto2://[usb:001,009]/

mv: cannot move `test.mp4' to `gphoto2://[usb:001,011]/': No such file or directory
```

how to copy file from my local  pc into my android phone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy files \*to\* a camera?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118718/how-to-copy-files-to-a-camera)

Comment: Interesting that it mentions gphoto2.  Does the question about copying files to a camera help at all?

Comment: These days, the way to transfer files to an Android device is called MTP.  See e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125845/mounting-an-mtp-enabled-device-on-ubuntu-12-04-3-lts-32-bit

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MTP seems to contain several useful pointers.

Comment: Another option is to just use `adb push` from the Android SDK platform tools. Tho it's not very elegant. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: You never said what distribution you were using on your PC.  Another useful-looking page: http://askubuntu.com/a/247046/1951

Comment: FYI, android.stackexchange.com exists, and your question would be on topic there, but I think is also on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

`gphoto2://…` is a URL, not a file name. Most programs expect file names, not URLs. In order to access a file, it needs to be on a [mounted filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)).

Android devices normally expose their filesystem via MTP. There are a couple of filesystems over MTP; see the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MTP#mtpfs) for some pointers. Look if your distribution has one of them packaged.

Alternatively, if you've managed to access the files over GPhoto in Gnome, you can make that available to all applications via [`gvfs-mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gvfs-mount.1.html). If the `gvfs-mount` program is not present on your system, install the corresponding package. `gvfs-mount` makes all Gnome file access methods available as filesystems. Older versions make them available under `~/.gvfs`, and newer ones under `/run/user/1234/gvfs` where 1234 is your user ID (you can see that with `echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` — which should be `/run/user/1234` — or `id -u`).

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable way is to run an ssh server on your phone. 
This does require your phone to be on the net, however.
That is what I am currently doing, but only to copy files from my android phone to my computer.

The SSH implementation I am using is [SimpleSSHD](http://www.galexander.org/software/simplesshd/). 
The instructions on that site should suffice for you to run SimpleSSHD on your phone. It is also on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.galexander.sshd&hl=en).

Once you have ssh working, you can use rsync to copy files back and forth.

This appears to be entirely a free software project, is easy to set up, and has worked flawlessly for me so far. The author has included a tarball of his git repository on his web page, but I do not see a link to the actual "live" repository, which is more standard.

NOTE: I'd like to give the author a review on Google Play, but unfortunately Google requires one to create a Google Plus account to do that, which I don't want you to do. If you already have a Google Plus account or don't mind creating one, I encourage you to add a review; there are not many so far.